# Client not communicating in a chat application

Tags: java, sockets, chat

I have created the multi chat application.

**Current Problem**
When I compile my class `Chatinterface` 2 times, 2 clients open up. Now When I am trying to communicate by typing a text message in the text area. The other client does not show the message and vice versa.

Can someone correct my code? and tell me what is happening.

Please don't be harsh I am only a beginner.

Please note I have provided the code of the server as well for a detailed explanation.

```
package stack;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

class Chatinterface implements ActionListener,Runnable {

    private JFrame chatwindow;
    JTextArea typemsg;
    JTextArea displaymsg;
    JButton sendbutton;
    JButton logoutbutton;
    Socket client;
    BufferedReader read;
    PrintWriter write;
    String getmsg;
    String gettext;
    public Chatinterface(){

        try {
            client = new Socket("localhost",3420);
            write = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        displaygui();
    }

    private void displaygui() {
        chatwindow = new JFrame();
        chatwindow.setResizable(false);
        chatwindow.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        chatwindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
        chatwindow.getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout);

        typemsg = new JTextArea();
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, typemsg, 171, SpringLayout.NORTH, chatwindow.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, typemsg, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, chatwindow.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, typemsg, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, chatwindow.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, typemsg, 340, SpringLayout.WEST, chatwindow.getContentPane());
        chatwindow.getContentPane().add(typemsg);

        displaymsg = new JTextArea();
        displaymsg.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        displaymsg.setEditable(false);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, displaymsg, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, chatwindow.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, displaymsg, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, typemsg);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, displaymsg, 160, SpringLayout.NORTH, chatwindow.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, displaymsg, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, typemsg);
        chatwindow.getContentPane().add(displaymsg);

        sendbutton = new JButton("Send");
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sendbutton, -76, SpringLayout.SOUTH, chatwindow.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sendbutton, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, typemsg);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, sendbutton, -27, SpringLayout.SOUTH, chatwindow.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, sendbutton, 82, SpringLayout.EAST, typemsg);
        chatwindow.getContentPane().add(sendbutton);
        sendbutton.addActionListener(this);
        sendbutton.setActionCommand("S");

        logoutbutton = new JButton("Logout");
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, logoutbutton, 50, SpringLayout.NORTH, chatwindow.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, logoutbutton, -65, SpringLayout.EAST, sendbutton);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, logoutbutton, 108, SpringLayout.NORTH, chatwindow.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, logoutbutton, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, sendbutton);
        chatwindow.getContentPane().add(logoutbutton);
        logoutbutton.addActionListener(this);
        logoutbutton.setActionCommand("L");
        chatwindow.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Chatinterface method = new Chatinterface();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread t1 = new Thread();
        t1.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("S"))
        {
            String gettext2;
            gettext2 = typemsg.getText();
            write.println(gettext2);
            displaymsg.append(gettext2+"\n");
            typemsg.setText("");
        }

        if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("L")){
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String readmsg;

        try {
            read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            readmsg = read.readLine();

            while(readmsg!=null)
            {

                displaymsg.append(readmsg);

            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the class handler that is invoked whenever a new client is connected.

```
package stack;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Handler implements Runnable {
    Socket s;

    String getmsg = null;
    String sendmsg;

    public Handler(Socket s) {
        this.s = s;

    }
    public void run() {
            BufferedReader reader1 = null;
            PrintWriter writer1 = null;

            try {
                reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        s.getInputStream()));
                writer1 = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                sendmsg = reader1.readLine();
                while (sendmsg!=null) {

                        writer1.println(sendmsg);

                }
                reader1.close();
                writer1.close();
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

    }
}
```

Here is the main server class

```
package stack;

import java.net.*;
public class Servera  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket s;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3420);

        while(true)
        {
            s = server.accept();
            Handler handler1 = new Handler(s);
            Thread t1 = new Thread(handler1);
            t1.start();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not getting message sent by client.For that you need to flush the OutputStream in client using **write.flush()**
Following will be the code change:

```
   if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("S"))
        {
            String gettext2;
            gettext2 = typemsg.getText();
            write.println(gettext2);
            write.flush()
            displaymsg.append(gettext2+"\n");
            typemsg.setText("");
        }
```

Also your logic for sending message from one client to another is not proper.As per your code the server will send message to same client from which it has received the message.FOr this you need to maintain the pool of client sockets and then broadcast the messages to all clients.Hope these answer your query.
Please accept the answer if it is right.

Comment: "For this you need to maintain the pool of client sockets and then broadcast the messages to all clients"- Could you please post a link to this ?

Comment: I have uploaded demo source of similar application http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gb6d4bd58cb31d3a699954007965bceee5ac777fdb please download it as soon as you can otherwise it will expire